# Converting the format in R (huge data)

Tags: r

I'm still a new user in R and I know there are tons of questions of converting wide format to long format. However, I fail to get the results that I want. I tried to use reshape, tidyr,, however, I still don't get the results that I want.

My data looks like below (it is just a part of it N)

```
     i1 i2 i3 i4 i5 i6 i7 i8 i9 i10 i11 i12 i13 i14 i15 i16 i17 i18 i19 i20 i21 i22 i23 i24 i25 i26 i27
207    0  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1
334    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
344    0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1
432    1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1
616    0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
667    1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

My ideal dataset

```
0 207 i1  => the observation of the 207th student at the first item. 
 1 207 i2
 0 207 i3
```

.
   .
Could somebody help me how to code? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried that hasn't worked? This seems like it should be covered by the wide-to-long classics like https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/5325862

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a row names column and then use `pivot_longer` to create a 3-column data.frame with rowname, column name and the values as the three columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
as.data.frame(m1) %>%
    rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -rn)
```

Comment: Right, and deleting the zeros gives you a more compact sparse normalized data set.

Answer (score 0):

Using `melt` from `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df, keep.rownames = T); melt(df, id.vars = "rn")
```